# How to resolve "SQL Anywhere Error -265: Procedure 'current_schema' not found" while configuring liquibase.properties for use with SAP IQ instance?

Tags: liquibase, sap-iq

I am having an issue getting Liquibase configured to connect to my database/schema on SAP IQ instance. An issue with the driver or I have the incorrect driver.

ERROR:

> SQL Anywhere Error -265: Procedure 'current_schema' not found

For example, `liquibase.properties` file contents:

```
classpath: C:/Users/[REDACTED]/AppData/Roaming/DBeaverData/drivers/drivers/sybase/jconnect/jconn4.jar
driver: com.sybase.jdbc4.jdbc.SybDriver
url: jdbc:sybase:Tds:{host}:{port}/{db}
username: *****
password: *****
```

See open issue: https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2051

Comment: Can you confirm which database are you using in here? Are you using SAP HANA (https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/sap-hana.html) or Sybase Anywhere (https://docs.liquibase.com/workflows/database-setup-tutorials/sybase-anywhere.html)?

Comment: There is an open issue about this on Liquibase github at
https://github.com/liquibase/liquibase/issues/2051

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and adding the `defaultSchemaName` property in the `liquibase.properties` resolved this error.